# Почему WebStorm добавляет комментарий, когда я с помощью emmeta пишу сокращенную запись элемента с классом?

Tags: webstorm, emmet

[image: Emmet добавляет ненужный комментарий]

Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему когда я в WebStorme пишу с помощью Emmeta сокращенную запись (Элемент с классом) то есть ставлю точку и пишу название класса (.nav) то Emmet дописывает сам потом снизу коментарий??? Не могу никак найти в настройках как это убрать... В остальном Emmet работает как надо. Заранее благодарю!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Похоже, у вас включен соответствующий фильтр. В **Settings | Editor | Emmet | HTML**, **Filters enabled by default**, отключите **Comment tags**

Comment: Лена, сердечно благодарю!! Да, так и было как Вы говорили. Сделал как Вы сказали, и проблема решилась! ОЧень благодарен Вам!!